# PhpStorm: How to add method stubs from a PECL library that PhpStorm doesn't currently support?

Tags: php, phpstorm

PhpStorm has a list of method stubs from various compile-time libraries [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs) that it will use for autocompletion in development.

I currently have a list of [stubs for the PHP AMQP PECL extension here](https://github.com/pdezwart/php-amqp/tree/master/stubs) that I would like to add to my PhpStorm build to get autocompletion for that library.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just place such stub file(s) anywhere in your project (or reference in any other supported way, e.g. as `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Include path`) -- IDE will use it for code completion (and similar) purposes only (so you can exclude them from uploading/VCS etc).

In long term -- you may submit the PR to the already mentioned [PhpStorm stubs repository](https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs) and it may become part of the standard PhpStorm distribution on next release.

Comment: On Mac it is `Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Include path`

Comment: Does anyone know how to EXCLUDE one of these built-in stubs, either on a global or project-specific basis? I need to "ignore" one of the stubs because it is conflicting with my own project code.

Comment: @MichaelButler No "nice" way unfortunately. Maybe one day in a future -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-5731. The "not-so-nice" way is to alter PhpStorm file with the stubs (it's a `.jar` file -- which is .zip inside) and remove unwanted stub from there. You can Ctrl+Click on such unwanted class/function to get into corresponding stub file (you need it to find out the path where that stub is stored). Then just alter original file (while IDE is closed, of course). NOTE that this would need to be done for each new IDE version .

Comment: @MichaelButler As of PhpStorm **2016.3** you can clone [PhpStorm stubs repository](https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs) and use it instead (where you can remove all unwanted stub files). The stubs are now listed under "External Libraries" branch of Project View panel .. and if you browse one of such files IDE will offer few actions on them (will be standard yellow notification bar on top of editor window). Default path to local copy can be configured in the same "Include Path" settings screen -- it now has collapsible "Advanced" section on the bottom.

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks a lot! Just did it and it works wonderfully. This is awesome since we can now create our own branches and sync with it.

Comment: I faced with supporting rdKafka and by this tip found what I need in PHP Runtime section, actually in PECL list. Maybe it will help to someone.

Answer (score 13):

January 2017 Update: You can `git clone` (checkout) the [PhpStorm stubs repository](https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs) to your local machine, and point PhpStorm to that directory. From there you can add stubs or even modify/delete existing stubs.

1. `git clone https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs`
2. Open Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP
3. Click Advanced Settings at the bottom
4. Next to Default stubs path, click the `...` and navigate to the root of your `phpstorm-stubs` folder

Comment: Do I have to do something to make it take affect other then press apply? It doesn't recognize SoapClient and its methods.

Answer (score 0):

Most extension stubs are already shipped and updated with PHPStorm, no need to download those stubs. `ampq` is supported as well (when writing this answer).

You can enable it in Settings > PHP > PHP Runtime.

`ampq` can be found in the tree under: PHP Runtime > Others.

If the extension is enabled in the configured interpreter, you can simply press the button "Sync Extensions with Interpreter".